# Store reference to object or specific functions

Tags: dependency-injection, encapsulation

Having single (or few) method(s) interface constructor injection should I store in a field a reference to the interface instance passed as is or just necessary "entry point(s)"?

```
class Client
{
    private readonly ITool _tool;
    public Client(ITool tool) => _tool = tool;
    ...
}
```

or

```
class Client
{
    private readonly Func<Input, Output> _applyTool;
    public Client(ITool tool) => _applyTool = tool.Apply;
    ...
}
```

The first way looks more common, but the second is more strict with encapsulation and it even possibly reduces code duplication in method invocations.

Comment: This is one of the cases where I think dependency injection has gone too far. What is "ITool" in your example ? Are you just trying to apply a functional style "map" to an object list or is it a tool/utility function like "string.Substring" ? Also, if you're talking about C#, you could pass a delegate (or lambda expression) as a parameter to Client, doing "public Client(Func<Input, Output> func), which renders your second option useless.

Comment: @Machado I tried to give most common example. How does an essence of the interface influence to decision in that case?

Comment: You haven't provided enough context in your question to make it answerable.  Dependency injection is a "big system" tool, and Foo Bar examples seldom provide enough detail for us to understand  your specific situation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's not my specific situation. It's not about DI. DI is out of scope here. It's about handling already injected stuff.

Comment: @SerG, it depends on what are you injecting. So the context of the object is important. There's **[no silver bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet)** on software engineering, and each solution may be optimal for a specific context.

Comment: @Machado so, could you specify please when each of two approach is applicable in so isolated abstract sense?

Comment: Not clear why you need the delegate, why you need the interface, what is the purpose of Client, etc.

Comment: @SerG, that's kind of easy, and I don't know if that's the answer you're looking for, but the first one you use when you need the whole ITool, and the second one I'd never use, if I just want a single delegate. I'd declare the second one as I said on my first comment: public Client(Func<Input, Output> func);

Comment: @SerG Your first sentence talks about "entry point(s)".  Am I right to assume that there might be several entry points one would wish to store? (Something in addition to `tool.Apply` like `tool.Recharge`?)

Comment: @Machado But it could be external causes to receive interface as parameter, more clear DI-container configuration for example. Also you can store not pure reference to method but wrapped with additional logic like: `_applyTool = (input) => tool.Apply(input).Filter().Convert()`

Comment: @ViktorSeifert Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a broad open question, but I'll bite!  Here's a really silly example.

Consider the following two interfaces:

```
interface IAdder
{
    int Combine(int a, int b);
}

interface IXorer
{
    int Combine(int a, int b);
}
```

These two interfaces appear to have the same methods, with the same name, and the same arguments. Yet they are treated as completely separate. There is no inheritance relationship. You can't accidentally use `IAdder` when you wanted to use `IXorer` (unless you do something extraordinarily weird).  ***You are protected from improper substitution by type safety.***

You can store a reference to one of these interfaces along with the type of the interface, thus ensuring that you will never XOR when you wish to ADD, or vice versa.

```
public Client(IAdder adder)
{
    _adder = adder;
}

public int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return _adder.Combine(a, b);  //Pretty darned sure this will add a and b
}
```

Not exactly rocket science so far, I hope.

Now let's say you don't want to store a pointer to the interface. Instead, you want to store a pointer to the function itself, as in your second example.  It might look like this:

```
private readonly Func<int, int, int> _combiner;

public Client(IAdder adder)
{
    _combiner = adder.Combine;
}
```

but you might also do this:

```
public Client(IXorer xorer)
{
    _combiner = xorer.Combine;
}
```

So, given the above, tell me... what does this code do?

```
return _combiner(a, b);  // Um..... ????
```

Does it add or xor? Oops, can't tell!

You now can no longer tell what a `_combiner` does from its type. It's just a function that takes two integers and returns a third. You have no idea what it does, other than what you can figure out by naming conventions and/or by tracing through code. ***You are not protected from improper substitution by type safety*** because the type of the delegate is not tied to any particular interface.

Maybe this is what you intended. If you just want `Client` to be able to send some data to some function with a particular signature, your second example communicates that well enough (we'll come back to that in a second). But if you intention is to tie the processing to a particular method of a particular interface, the indirection caused by the delegate makes you lose that information, and makes the code harder to read, and more prone to error.

And imagine you're a developer and you're reverse engineering this code a few months later... you find the call to the delegate and hit F12 to find out where it goes, and all it tells you is the method signature. Now you have to do a code search to figure out who set that variable. And if it is set more than once, who set it *when.* What a nightmare! Why, it's almost like working with procedural BASIC with a bunch of global variables.  If you had stored the interface, the engineer would at least know where to look to find out what it's supposed to do.

Based on this reasoning, my preference is typically to inject, store, and use the interface, in order to leverage the type safety as a means of ensuring semantic correctness.

Now, what if you want to be able to switch out `adder` and `xorer` at run time? Certainly storing only the method will let you do that without much effort. But you could also accidentally put in any function that takes two integers and outputs a third, and I'm guessing there are quite a few of those in the universe. So a better way to do it would be to stick with the interfaces:

```
interface ICombiner
{
    int Combine(int a, int b);
}

interface IAdder : ICombiner {}

interface IXorer : ICombiner {}
```

Now as a programmer you have the ability to completely control what can be substituted and what can't, which is exactly how interfaces are meant to be used. You can't do that with delegates.

TLDR: Use the first method, unless you have a compelling reason to use the second method.

Comment: Nice explanation. I wonder why OP-commenters are stuck to concrete realization as if they didn't hear about things like pattern, style or common practices.